# Buckingham-$\pi$ doesn't work on Lotka-Volterra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, dimensional-analysis

Given the Lotka-Volterra system:
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=aR-bRF$$
$$\frac{dF}{dt}=-cF+dRF$$

I think Buckingham-$\pi$ predicts that - since there are 7 variables (R, F, a, b, c, d, t), and 2 units (# of animals, time), the system can be expressed in 7 - 2 = 5 dimensionless variables.

However when I do the standard nondimensionalization, I get:
$$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=x(1-y)$$
$$\frac{dy}{d\tau}=\mu y(x-1)$$

Where $\tau$ stands for dimensionless time. There are only 4 variables total, not five. What went wrong? I've been using Buckingham-Pi for other systems in the same way and they've worked out fine.

Comment: There's actually three units, because I'm assuming (without context you have not provided) R and F are measuring the numbers of two distinct animals in some kind of predator prey model.

Comment: Ah, you're right, there are three units (# of R animal, # of F animal, time). Thanks!

Comment: Dosen’t the theorem only give an upper limit?